# Why are watches in jewellery adverts set to ten to two?

Tags: marketing

Or ten past ten. The usual answer is that it resembles a smile and increases sales but it sounds to me more like an urban myth that has got out of hand.

What's the truth? Is there really any **evidence** that setting clocks and watches to this time encourages sales? Or is everyone doing this simply because everyone else is?

**Update:** I'm looking for evidence / proof, e.g. a scientific study or real marketing research.

Comment: Around here jewelers display working watches...

Comment: This is also the recommended position for hand position on a steering wheel while driving.  I sense a conspiracy here....

Comment: I changed the title to reference adverts, where it is more common.

Comment: You are giving away the secret to my psychic mind-reading trick. The hard part is to get them to open a random magazine and find a random watch ad. Then get them to focus on the time without showing me. "I am getting a strong sense of the number 10...."

Comment: Apparently even **[Cecil Adams](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/547/why-are-clocks-in-ads-always-set-at-8-20)** cannot answer this!

Comment: Downvote because the question in the title was clearly answered. Instead of updating the question (and moving the goalposts) it would have been better to open another question weather or not the technique is effective.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[image: Watches] <sup>[Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Mens-Watches/b/ref=wa_leftnav_abb_v2_dept_mens?ie=UTF8&node=404124011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=left-4&pf_rd_r=1CXQDPQV28STY3PY6KGR&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1310060522&pf_rd_i=377110011)</sup>

From [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/28/business/media/28adco.html) (2008):

> ... **the explanation turns out to be a simple matter of aesthetics.**

[...]

> In a recent check of the 100 top-selling men’s dress watches on
> "*Amazon.com* ", which included models from 20 brands, all but three
> watches were set to 10:10.
>
> **Because brand names generally are centered on the upper half of a
> watch, hands positioned at 10 and 2 “*frame the brand and logo*,”** said
> Andrew Block, executive vice president at **Tourneau**, the watch
> retailer, which has 51 stores worldwide.
>
> “*It’s almost like an
> unwritten rule that everyone understands to photograph a watch a
> 10:10*.”

[...]

> “***It has the aesthetic of the smiley face to be 10 past 10, so we try
> whenever possible to opt for that***,” Susanne Hurni, head of **Ulysse
> Nardin**’s advertising and marketing, said from the company headquarters
> in Le Locle, Switzerland.

[...]

> Klaus Peter Mager, a spokesman for **Swatch**, said his 25-year-old
> company, based in Biel, Switzerland, has always photographed watches
> primarily at 10:10, because “***they’re smiling instead of a sad man’s
> face.***”

[...]

> **Timex** has an official time, 10:09:36, at which every watch — even digital models — is photographed for marketing purposes.

[...]

> **At Rolex, watches are always photographed at 10:10:31**, and for models
> that list the day of the week and calendar day, it is always Monday
> the 28th.

[...]

> “*In advertising we would never expect someone to look at a watch and
> say, ‘The watch is smiling,’ but it’s just a feeling you get,* ” said
> Ms. Kaplan Thaler, co-author, with Robin Koval, of “[The Power of
> Nice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385518927),” which features a big smile on its cover.
>
> The watch theme, she
> added, is typical of “*subconscious cues that are used in print ads.* ”

**More:**

- [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/business/market/clockhands.asp) debunks the myth that the 10:10 position is a tribute to John F. Kennedy's death.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but this seems to be just confirming the question. I want to know if there is any truth that it helps watch sales, or do people do it simply because *everyone else does it*, hence my skepticism. I have clarified my question now.

Comment: @Wikis - Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Thought you were wondering if "Set to 10:10 because it resembles a smile" is a myth. But you are actually asking if a "smile" increases sales.

Comment: The very first point is the answer mate. It frames the brand and logo. You dont need to go further. Better the branding, better the sales

Comment: @Pankaj: really? Do you have proof?

Comment: @Oliver_C: no problem, it is good to clarify this. My apologies for not being more clear.

Comment: Some question don't really need proofs or the other way round, no one can carry out a proof theorem for some question. This one lies in the same vicinity. This thing doesn't come under a branding strategy(though its used for framing the brand) and no one can ever prove the sales figure in this regard. It's just like the TV channel logo; preferred on the top-left, but placing it on bottom-left won't decrease the viewership. It's the content that matters in both the cases.

Comment: I always thought the 10:10 position was a V check-mark, not a smiley face...

Comment: I know this is a long time later but I have re-read your answer and realised that it does indeed answer my question, hence I have accepted. Apologies for the delay!